# NHibernate 3.2 Mapping by code - can you map to private fields for Id and bag?

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

e.g.

```
this.Bag(
                r => "privatefieldtomap",
                map =>
                    {
                        map.Access(Access.Field);
                        map.Table("table");
                        map.Key(k => k.Column("foreignkey"));
                    },
                r => r.Element(m => m.Column("columntomap")));

public SomeType()
        {
            this.Id(p => "privateidfield", Access(Access.Field));
            this.Table("SomeTable");
            this.Property(p => p.SomeProperty);
        }
```

both throw an exception "expression expected; constant found"

We could do this using xml mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Answer here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/wiH1DPGOhgU turns out there is an overload that accepts a string as first parameter whereas I was using a lambda expression.